# How to parametrize a variable inside sh and sed

Tags: shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to parametrize a variable inside sh and sed  where I need to use single quotes in sh.
when I am using three double quotes it is working fine but when I used three single quotes variable is not getting parametrized

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
      source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

      cat /proc/meminfo

      echo 'In credentails'
      sed -i '/:LOGINID:/ c\\:LOGINID: ${UID}' "${WORKSPACE}/test/data/TEST.TXT"
      sed -i '/:LOGINPWD:/ c\\:LOGINPWD: ${PWD}' "${WORKSPACE}/test/data/TEST.TXT"
   '''
```

The problem is ${UID} and ${PWD} values are not getting parametrized and I should use only single quotes after sh

Comment: Did you try double quotes `""`?  Shell variables like `$UID` are interpolated inside double quotes, not inside single quotes.

Comment: with double quotes it is working but I need to use single quotes because Jenkins is throwing a warning have insecure interpolation of sensitive variables when I use double quotes.

Comment: How are these parameters defined in your pipeline? In general if you want the parameters to be interpolated during the shell command execution use single quotes for the string, and use  the shell syntax for environment variables: `$UID`, `$PWD`, `$WORKSPACE` .